# Installing IDE and GUI inside Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to make a development environment in elastic beanstalk, which will be similar to a production environment.

I would like to have an IDE installed in the environment, and have graphical desktop to work with. I can create all this in a new instance, and create an AMI out of it, but that will not work with Elastic beanstalk.

Amazon Linux doesn't allow you to install a GUI, and i have been unable to find a Red Hat AMI that works with Elastic Beanstalk, or create one.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are opposing production and development, but when you do that the "development" environment is not where you actually execute your IDE. A better name is "testing" environment.

You want to have your development (graphical desktop, IDE, whatever) on your machine (just maybe in a VM). Then you export your deliverables (code, any files you develop) to your testing environment to see if they work, and then to your production environment so that they actually do work.

Comment: The only problem with that suggestion is incoming request will have a different path outside of beanstalk. For instance, in beanstalk, requests are going through nginx, through Wsgi, through docker, to django. Outside beanstalk, request are not going through nginx. Thus why i want a development environment in beanstalk.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what your IDE and graphical user environment have to do with incoming requests to your website.